# How can I discover all tests in solution from Visual Studio extension?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I'm building a Visual Studio extension (targeting primarily VS 2017). I'd like the extension to hook in on the build event OnBuildDone and automatically run all tests after a successful build is done. So far I've managed to hook in on the BuildEvent, and I've tried the following solutions:

```
// Solution 1, works but only runs the already discovered tests
IDisposableQuery<ITest> tests = await TestsService.GetTestsAsync();
await TestsService.RunTestsAsync(tests.Select(t => t.Id));

// Solution 2, works but also rebuilds the project (redundantly)
// and emits the OnBuildDone event (causing an infinite recursion loop)
dte.ExecuteCommand("TestExplorer.RunAllTests");
```

Ultimately I'd like to go with the first solution *but start* with running a test discovery to refresh all available tests to run. I've searched through the (non)existing documentation on how to do this without any luck.

Any ideas on how to achieve that?